# download big file with limt upstream ,post file

Tags: php, nginx, download, vps

on  jumpstarter.io
i have project php 
i want dowload file larger from server via HTTP [php]
 file size limit  = 30 MB for post file

i can't  config   http {} of the nginx.conf file normally located at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
and php.ini

Editable :

```
NginX Configuration
  server {
       listen 0.0.0.0;
       root /var/www;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;

       location / { 
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
       }
       location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }

       location = /robots.txt {
              allow all;
              log_not_found off;
              access_log off;
       }

      # location ~* \\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
              #  expires 2w;
      # }



       location ~* \\.php$ {
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "
                display_errors=On
                display_startup_errors=On
                error_reporting=30719
                ";
       }


}
```

Default:    /etc/nginx/nginx.conf  (can't edit)

```
user http;
worker_processes 2;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
daemon off;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}
http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 20m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    # logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log;
    # gzip
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    # vhost
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Anyone help me . thanks

Comment: And error 502 Gateway  faiulure   if download .

Comment: a post limit on a server will have absolutely no effect on **(GET)TING** a file from that server. which server has this 30meg limit?

Comment: @ Marc B yes, it limit, I try to use download chunked  but it not sussces , if have add header('Content-Length: $filesize ); -> error post file limit.